# Debugger unable to show global array values

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 and the code is written in Visual C++. While debugging, if I am declaring my arrays as global I am unable to see their values, while debugging instead it is showing garbage values. I am unable to understand the root cause for this.

If there is any other way to declare the array please do let me know.
This is how I declared the buffers:

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char message_buff[1000] = { 0 };
static char buffer[100] = { 0 };
char data[100] = { 0 };//another buffer to store data // int to char changedby me//buffer to store cell ID and LAC
int tower[1000] = { 0 };   // tower no
int signal[1000] = { 0 };  // signal strength
int mccbuff[1000] = { 0 }; // mcc buf
int mncbuff[1000] = { 0 }; // mnc buffer
int count = 0;
int decimal_to_ascii(int value)  //logic to get the ascii value from decimal 

void clearbuffer(char *p)
{
}
int data_fetch()
{

}

using namespace std;
```

and that's the output:

[image]

Comment: No way to tell without MCVE. Could you reproduce this behavior on the empty project with global char array?

Comment: Sometime this happen to my VS too.  I have to add a :: before var to show it.